# Keeping aspect ratio for images with percentage width & resizing other divs while keeping aspect ration

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure out a way of making the image div having and keeping an aspect ratio of 3:2 with different web browser sizes (for mobile responsiveness etc). I want to be able to re-size my browser window and the image to always have a 3:2, so I want the image height to also re-size.

Is there any way of achieving this with my current code? I'd also like to be able to make the blue text div smaller without having to make the image above bigger, because if I reduce the height percentage of the blue div, I'll have to increase the picture div above to make up the 100% parent element's height, but this will throw the aspect ratio of the picture div out.

I'm not sure how to achieve this as it's more confusing than I thought.

Appreciate any help, thanks...

```css
#bg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background: yellow;
}
#window-container {
  width: 30%;
  height: 200px;
  background: orange;
}
#img {
  background: url('http://www.livescience.com/images/i/000/036/988/original/elephants.jpg');
  height: 67%;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
#text-wrap {
  background: lightblue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 33%;
}
```

```html
<div id="bg">
  <div id='window-container'>
    <div id='img'></div>
    <div id='text-wrap'>text here</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're lucky. `%`-values for `padding` and `margin` always refer to the `width` of an element, even if applied to `padding-bottom` or `padding-top`. With this knowledge you should easily be able to find a solution that makes sure the aspect ratio stays the same.

Comment: still not sure. Won't applying a margin increase the gap between the image and the blue div, and padding would only push the text down but the blue div would remain the same size?

Comment: How flexible can I be with other width & height values?

Comment: as long as the aspect ratio is maintained and the blue div is resizable then it's ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May this be what you want?

```css
#bg {
  width: 100%;
  background: yellow;
  display: table;
}
#window-container {
  width: 30%;
  background: orange;
  display: block;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
#text-wrap {
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="bg">
  <div id='window-container'>
    <img src="https://www.livescience.com/images/i/000/036/988/original/elephants.jpg" alt="">
    <div id='text-wrap'>text here</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that seems like it, thanks! presumably you can adjust the 'height' of the blue div using the padding - or anyway, it seems to respond its height to accommodate more text

Comment: Not vertically responsive.

Comment: what do you mean? resizing the browser window also resizes the image to keep its aspect ratio

Comment: @VXp vertically responsive?

Comment: Resize it from below.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the `img` element and ***Flexbox***:

```css
#bg {
  background: yellow;
}

#window-container {
  display: inline-flex; /* only takes the contents width */
  flex-direction: column; /* stacks children vertically */
  background: orange;
}

#text-wrap {
  background: lightblue;
}

img {
  display: block; /* removes bottom margin/whitespace */
  /*height: 66.66%; more accurate, needs to be commented out in order to work in Chrome, in FF it works perfectly, so the solution is to use properly cropped (3:2 ratio) locally stored images, luckily that's not the case with the current image*/
  max-width: 100%; /* horizontal responsiveness */
  max-height: 100vh; /* vertical responsiveness */
}
```

```html
<div id="bg">
  <div id='window-container'>
    <img src="http://www.livescience.com/images/i/000/036/988/original/elephants.jpg" alt="">
    <div id='text-wrap'>text here</div>
  </div>
</div>
```